# Python flet on termux, is it even possible?

Tags: python, termux, flet

Flet is a relatively new but powerful technology and I'm currently working on a flet desktop project, but I want to work on it while I'm not home and I don't know if flet and termux are ready to work together yet.

### What I'm looking for

Flet projects with hot reload running on Android

### My device

- Lenovo TAB 3rdGen
- Android 12
- aarch64

### steps followed

- Install termux from f-droid
- Install python
  `pkg install python`
- install pip
  `pkg install python-pip`
- try install flet
  `pip install flet`
- getting rust compiler not found error
- install rust **successfully** `pkg install rust`
- try again
- getting this error

```
Running `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-dwruddbi/maturin_72d4713a9e85448ca459f39c0a54cc6e/target/release/build/psm-a05bc41960736b49/build-script-build`
            error: failed to run custom build command for `psm v0.1.21`

            Caused by:
              process didn't exit successfully: `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-dwruddbi/maturin_72d4713a9e85448ca459f39c0a54cc6e/target/release/build/psm-a05bc41960736b49/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
              --- stdout
              OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
              TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
              HOST = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64-linux-android
              CC_aarch64-linux-android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64_linux_android
              CC_aarch64_linux_android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
              HOST_CC = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
              CC = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
              CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
              DEBUG = Some("false")
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android
              CFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android
              CFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
              HOST_CFLAGS = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
              CFLAGS = None
              cargo:rustc-cfg=asm
              cargo:rustc-cfg=switchable_stack
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR_aarch64-linux-android
              AR_aarch64-linux-android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR_aarch64_linux_android
              AR_aarch64_linux_android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_AR
              HOST_AR = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR
              AR = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android
              ARFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android
              ARFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_ARFLAGS
              HOST_ARFLAGS = None
              cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS
              ARFLAGS = None

              --- stderr


              error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `aarch64-linux-android-ar` installed?


            warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
            error: `cargo build --manifest-path Cargo.toml --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --release -v --no-default-features --locked` failed with code 101
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

### GitHub codespace

I know I could use a GitHub codespace, Python compiles flet projects there using `python main.py` but in order to use hot reload You have to use `flet run main.py` which gives me other error I'm making another post for.

### edit

Seems like I forgot to Say that I installed rust successfully when I first posted the question, that works just fine, It's the next step the one that stops me

Comment: (per answers on the linked duplicate, you want `pkg install rust`)

Comment: It worked when I installed binutils via `pkg install binutils`

Comment: Indeed. Centering the `aarch64-linux-android-ar` error in the question would have made that a lot more obvious.